# Which file do you insert your custom code to use wp-client action hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to figure which file you actually place your custom code to use a wp-client plugin action hook.  The action hook in particular I'm trying to use is the "wpc_client_new_client_registered" hook.

The WordPress site itself uses the WP-CLIENT and WOOCOMMERCE plug-ins.

I need to invoke a 3rd party REST API when a new register fills out the registration form right before checking out of the "products" (a monthly subscription basically to online software) cart.

I also need to invoke a 3rd party REST API whenever an existing user makes changes to their current subscriptions in WOOCOMMERCE.

Looked through the documentation but I don't recall finding out which actual file(s) you modify.

Please advise, I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Comment: You can find the [hooks that woocommerce provides here](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html). Furthemore, you can just put them in functions.php within your theme.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I need the file I can out my code in for the WP-CLIENT.  Their documentation provides all the hook names but not the file name to place them in.

Comment: I would advise you not to put this in your theme's `functions.php`. Your theme should be reserved for appearance-related functions. Funcationality mods should go in their [own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header)